# .net component to draw ternary diagram?

Tags: c#, .net, plot, ternary

For a winform application written in C# (4.0 for framework or less), we need to display data in a [ternary diagram](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ternary_plot).

Do somebody know a graphical component written in C# that can be used? (open-source or not)

We want to be able to :

- zoom/unzoom on this diagram,
- resize the form where is displayed
- this graph  have tooltips on each point
- draw an envelop curve

thank you